# ¿A qué se refiere con error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’? C++

Tags: c++, condiciones

agradecería mucho si alguien puede ayudarme con el siguiente problema. Soy nueva en programación y no entiendo muy bien el error que me arroja este código, estoy haciendo un programa que pregunte los tipos de animales, y que en resultado  estándar escriba cuales son: ovíparos, vivíparos y ovovivíparos.

El código que he hecho:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int
main ()
{

  string animal;

  cout << endl << "******************Los tipos de animales******************"
    << endl;
    
  cout << endl <<
  "Ingrese uno de los animales siguientes para saber si es ovíparo, vivíparo o ovovivíparro (solo utilizar mayúsculas): " << endl;
  cout << "OSO" << endl;
  cout << "LEON" << endl;
  cout << "BALLENA" << endl;
  cout << "PINGUINO" << endl;
  cout << "HORMIGA" << endl;
  cout << "GALLINA" << endl;
  cout << "ORNITORRINCO" << endl;
  cout << "MANTARAYAS" << endl;
  cout << "Selección: ";
  cin >> animal;
  
  if (animal == "OSO" || animal == "LEON" || animal == "BALLENA")
  {
      cout << endl << "El animal es vivíparo porque se forman en el vientre materno." << endl;
  } 
    
  else if (animal == "PINGUINO" || animal == "HORMIGA" || animal == "GALLINA")
  {
      cout << endl << "El animal es ovíparo porque se forman dentro de un huevo." << endl;
  }
  
  else if (animal == "ORNITORRINCO" || animal == "MANTARAYAS");
  {
      cout << endl << "El animal es ovivíparo porque se forman dentro de un huevo que está dentro del vientre materno." << endl;
  }

  else 
  {
      cout << endl << "El animal no está dentro de las opciones";
  }
    
  return 0;
}
```

El error que me arroja:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:54:3: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
   else
   ^~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

borra el `;` de `else if (animal == "ORNITORRINCO" || animal == "MANTARAYAS");`